# How to check memory type and speed?

Tags: command-line, ram

I want to get more RAM for my computer, and I understand that to get the right type of RAM I have to know the memory type and speed (minimum and maximum as far as I understand). So how do I find these things out? And is there anything I need to know about the memory before I can get more RAM which will actually fit with the specifications of my computer? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20.

**Note:** I know that there are Terminal commands to find out this information, I just can't remember what they are.

Comment: I've always just looked up my computer make and model on a reputable RAM seller's website, like http://crucial.com 's "Advisor Tool", to get that information

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `lshw` to display memory information:

```
sudo lshw -c memory
```

It will display RAM as well as CPU caches, but you can quickly find the information you want.

One example memory module could look like this:

```
 *-bank:0
      description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
      product: ACR16D3LS1KNG/8G
      vendor: Kingston
      physical id: 0
      serial: 16392411
      slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
      size: 8GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
```